# How to tab without losing block

Tags: vim

I have been using vim for about 3 weeks now and have been having problem with tabs.

What I usually do is do `gg` to go to the top, do a `ctrl+v` for visual block, do a `G` to select everything to below(one column), do a `$` to select to the right, then press `<` or `>` to tab.

However having to do all this, I lose the selection and I have to do all those commands to do another tab.

How do I not lose selection? Or is there a better way?

NOTE: I sometimes don't need to select everything sometimes just a portion of the file.

Comment: did you try `>>` or `number>>`, say `10>>`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To reselect a visual selection use the `gv` command followed by your command. Although this is not the best way.

Instead select the whole buffer with `ggVG` then indent with `>`. This will indent the selection. To repeat the command again just press `.`. The `.` command will repeat the last normal command, in this case the `>` command. If you have indent a few times to many just use the undo command, `u`, as many times as necessary. This [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/modal-editing-undo-redo-and-repeat/) is a great screencast describing this technique and [this one](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/indentation-commands/) describe more indention techniques.

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442302/tabbing-selected-section-in-vim) prefer the following mappings:

```
xnoremap <Tab> >gv
xnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what is important here: being able to do multiple indents in a single go or keeping the visual block.  Assuming you want to do multiple indents, just prefix the `>` with a number, e.g. `3>` will indent the selected block three times.

Also, you don't need to select the entire line to indent it (i.e. the `$` is not needed).