# Tabbing visual selection in VIM don't work as expected

Tags: vi

A related question: [Tabbing visual selection in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442302/tabbing-visual-selection-in-vim)

I want to put tabs to the beginning of a text on VIM. More specifically, what I want to do is the following,

Before:

```
Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum
Lorem lorem lorem lorem
Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum
```

After:

```
^ILorem ipsum ipsum ipsum
^ILorem lorem lorem lorem
^ILorem ipsum ipsum ipsum
```

Note that `^I` is the tab character. So, I don't want VIM to use whitespaces to indent my code. What I am doing for now to pursue this is the following,

```
1. Visually select lines using: <SHIFT + v> jjj 
2. Indent lines using: >
```

However, this results me the following,

```
^I^I  Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum
^I^I  Lorem lorem lorem lorem
^I^I  Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum
```

Note that there are two tabs in the beginning of the line and two whitespaces, then `Lorem ipsum..` text is starting..

Why do I have `'^I^I  '` in the beginning of the line and do not have only `'^I'`?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for VIM is to indent one tabstop per `>>`.
If any other behaviour is present, it is probably because some other setting is present in your .vimrc-file.

If this for some reason is not the case, you can edit this setting yourself by adding `set tabstop=0` to your .vimrc-file.

Another tip is to use movements together with you commands. Instead of selecting the lines and press `j` three times, simply go to the first line and type `3>>`. This way the three following lines will be indented.